# Proving a partial differential equation of a $U(x_1,x_2)$ function depends on $x_1-x_2$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification

This is my first time doing differential equations instead of just learning about it and I have no idea where to start with this one.

With this equation :

$$
\frac{\partial U}{\partial x_1} + \frac{\partial U}{\partial x_2} = 0
$$

I need to prove that $U$ is only dependent on $x_1-x_2$.

I have these following conditions:

- $x_1$ and $x_2$ are Cartesian coordinates.
- The following variables exist:
  $$
  \epsilon = x_1 + x_2,
  $$
  $$
  \eta = x_1 - x_2;
  $$
  both of them are independent and correspond to oblique, $45$-degree coordinates on the $(x_1,x_2)$ plane.

Comment: Either $\epsilon$ or $\eta$ should have a minus in it.

Comment: u are right! i will correct it in a sec

Answer (score 0):

$f(t)=U(x_1+t,x_2+t)$ has $f'(t)=0$ so $f$ is a constant. But if $z_1-z_2=x_1-x_2$ then there is a $t$ such that $(z_1,z_2)=(x_1+t,x_2+t)$.

Comment: Please, can you explain how did you reach to that solution?

Comment: What step don't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Let $V(x,y):=U(x+y,x-y)$.

Then

$$\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial y}=0$$ and $V$ is a function of $y$ alone.

Comment: so are the variables in the question useless?

Comment: @ScaryMonsters: what do you think ?

Comment: well they form part of function V and maybe the fact they are independent allow them for the partial derivative of V become an addition of dUx and dUy, but i don't get why the question included Cartesian coordinates, the fact they are oblique and with a 45 degree angle.

Comment: @ScaryMonsters: look closer at my answer.

Comment: well, it shows that they cross at one point and if we put the 2 variables together we should find their angle equal to 45

Comment: my brain is fried, i don't even know what the partial devatives of U and V look like in a graph.